# MongoDB - Tie user to specific replica set node

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way in MongoDB 3.0 to allow users access to only a single replica set node?

We have a lot more data on disk than we do memory.  So to keep our production support from paging into memory data that is not needed by our applications, we would like to designate the primary and a couple secondaries for our applications and a single secondary for read-only prod support access.  Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: I've added an answer to your question; but to be honest, this approach isn't how MongoDB was designed. To address problems of your data not fitting in memory, you'd be better off with two different approaches: 1, adding more RAM; and 2, sharding your data so there's less data needing to fit into each node's RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In part, yes; in part, no.

Yes: you can direct *reads* to secondary node, using a suitable [readPreference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) - perhaps based on nodes being [tagged](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/)/. However, if you relying on a particular secondary node being available then you can run into real difficulties if that particular node goes down, so beware.

No: [all *writes* will go to the Primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#replica-set-members), and there's nothing you can do to change that. If your production support needs to do any writes at all (even side-effect writes such as login auditing), that will affect which data is held in memory.